# display image from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day! I am trying to retrieve from image path with the name stored from database but I am struggling to display that image from folder and I'll explain you that later... here is my code.

in my **controller**

```
public function save()
{
    $url = $this->do_upload();
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $this->main_m->save($title, $url);
}

public function do_upload()
{
    $type = explode('.', $_FILES["pic"] ["name"]);
    $type = $type[count($type)-1];
    $url = "./images/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
    if(in_array($type, array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png")))
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]))
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $url))
    return $url;
}
```

in my **view** im trying to retrieve like this.

```
 <?php foreach ($this->b->getalldata() as $row) {
      echo '<li>'.
                '<a class="ns-img" href="'.base_url("images/".$row->image).'".></a>'.
                '<div class="caption">'.$row->title.'</div>'.
          '</li>';
              } ?>
```

in my **model**

```
public function save($title, $url)
{
    $this->db->set('title', $title);
    $this->db->set('image', $url);
    $this->db->insert('slider');
}
```

the image stored to path folder and also the new name of the image stored to database but displaying the image like that is not working for me. my image path folder is "images" and the image name stored to database is "./images/new_name.jpg" not the same name as image that stored to the folder path. the image name that stored to folder path has no ./images/ only new_name.jpg...

how to display that image? someone tried that? help!

Comment: Please post the code in saving the image url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode image name from "./images/new_name.jpg".

```
$image_arr = explode("/", "./images/new_name.jpg");

echo $image_name = end($image_arr);
```

Comment: sir that new_name.jpg is not always the name of the image because im using uniqid(rand())..

Comment: In foreach condition you have to image name as $row->image. You can make new_image.jpg to dymanic.

Comment: You code would be <?php foreach ($this->b->getalldata() as $row) {$image_arr = explode("/", $row->image);

   $image_name = end($image_arr);
      echo '<li>'.
                '<a class="ns-img" href="'.base_url("images/".$image_name).'".></a>'.
                '<div class="caption">'.$row->title.'</div>'.
          '</li>';
              } ?>

Comment: here is what page source rendered <a class="ns-img" href="http://localhost/nmsc/images/./images/2986456b874d4b1620.png".></a>      the image name from database is ./images/2986456b874d4b1620.png but the name of image from the path folder is only 2986456b874d4b1620.png

Comment: Use this line to render image <a class="ns-img" href="<?php echo base_url()?>/images/<?php echo $image_name?>"></a>

Comment: not working as well. if the this <?php echo base_url()?>/images/ render as localhost/nmsc/images/ and the <?php echo $image_name?> render as ./images/2986456b874d4b1620 it seems doesn't work.. maybe my problem is on how the image upload...

Comment: <?php echo $image_name?> should be 2986456b874d4b1620.jpg.    Before rendering use $image_arr = explode("/", $row->image);

echo $image_name = end($image_arr); code.

Comment: now my slider image works..  so the explode remove the last slash right? I have 2 images name stored from database the 1 has ./images/  before the image name and the other had no ./images/  only the image name but that 2 images displayed to my slider it means the explode will remove all slashes and  automatically skip the other that had no ./images/. correct me if i'm wrong..

Answer (score 0):

> we used codeigniter upload library

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib');
         $config = array(
                        'upload_path' => APPPATH."upload/folder",
                        'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
                        'overwrite' => TRUE,
                        'max_size' => "2048000"
                    );


  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  $this->upload->do_upload('pic');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `img` HTML tag:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/' . $row->image);?>">
```

Comment: can I use that img tag? Im using that anchor tag in purpose because im using that images to my slide Images

Comment: You can wrap image into link `<a href="location"><img src='loc.jpg'></a>`, but in order to see an image, image need to be within `img` tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

On view

```
 <?php foreach ($this->b->getalldata() as $row) {
     echo '<li>'.
       '<a class="ns-img" href="#">'.base_url().'images/'.$row->image.'</a>'.
            '<div class="caption">'.$row->title.'</div>'.
      '</li>';
   } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have error here `.base_url("images/".$row->image).'`n try to use `site_url('images').'/'.$row->image`
i hope you will get the proper path of your file.

Comment: if still facing an issue check your .htaccess file to ensure that you give permissions for images folder.

Comment: its not working sir Azam, the result rendered from the page source is <a class="ns-img" href="http://localhost/nmsc/images/./images/300956b8791fe5c4e.jpg".></a>

Comment: use site_url() instead of site_url('images')

Comment: use echo with site_url too

Comment: the page source rendered like this href="http://localhost/nmsc/images/./images/2986456b874d4b1620.png" as i said earlier my folder path is images then if I use base_url('images')  the result is http://localhost/nmsc/images/ thats right.... the image name too from database is ./images/2986456b874d4b1620.png if we combine that 2 the result is href="http://localhost/nmsc/images/./images/2986456b874d4b1620.png

Comment: then remove 'images' that  you are giving before your database image name.

Comment: If I do that the image name from database will remove the ./images/ but the problem is it didn't upload the image to the path folder

Comment: path should be generated only when image is uploaded. let me know if you have any issue in image upload too

Comment: no. i don't have an issue... but some syntax bothered my mind... this line $url = "./images/".uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type; if i remove that .images/ the image name that store to database is only the name of the image but no image store to the path folder then I tried also to edit the image name from  phpadmin to remove that ./images/ and the image display to my page...